# Script doesn't run after load a div with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, audiojs

I have the script audiojs for changing the style of audios tag in html when I go to my page it work without problems, but when I click a button to reload div (this div contain audios tags) with function load jQuery the style of audiojs removed, I tried to get script after load the div with jQuery `getScript`, but the script load many times that caused to stop of my browser.

this is the function to call the audiojs

```
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
  audiojs.createAll();
});
```

I want a solution to call this function one time no more, thanks

Comment: if you "reload" the div, you lose changes you made, so either don't reload or re-apply if you do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone,

i found the solution,

after loading the div with ajax i added this code to remove the class audiojs

`$("audio").removeClass("audiojs");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding a new script tag to  with the script to re-load in your code something like below:

```js
 <script language="text/javascript">
   function audiojs()
   {
      var div= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= 'audiojs.js';
      div.appendChild(script);
   }
   audiojs();
</script>
```

I hope you will get some ideas now. Also check your caching.

Comment: I think that the probleme is not from script tag, i think that is from this function audiojs.createAll(), so i want an if statement to check if this function is also running or no . this is a docs for the lib rary if you want https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/ TAHNKS

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without any link to the audio.js library, but most API's or libraries will give some indication that they are loaded.  I would use an if statement to create something like:

```
(function () {
 function checkForLoaded(){
   if (audiojs.state !== null) { //or something similar
      audiojs.createAll();
   }
 }
})();
```

Comment: sorry, but this library doesn't use a function that get the state, this is a docs of library https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/ , THANK YOU